# How to integrate Spring AOP in CDI - any examples

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, cdi, aop, aspect

I would implement a Spring aspect in a j2ee application, can someone post some tutorials?

I've just used Spring in web application but I've not idea how to invoke a cross cutting concern in CDI container.

Thanks in advance

Comment: spring aop is not related to j2ee or web specifics

Answer (score 1):

Is there a special need for combining Spring and CDI? If not, I'd suggest to stick to standard Java EE as long as you can solve your problem with it and only if not, look for external components (and even then, you should first check the "sort-of-standard" CDI extensionf from the [Apache Deltaspike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/) project.

Cross-cutting concerns can be solved via pure CDI - check our for example the [Java EE 7 tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv006.htm#GKHJX) about the topic.

*Small note: Don't use J2EE anymore if not maintaining an ancient application.*